# Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using SpringBoot2 2.1.6.RELEASE and Java 11.
Calling 3rd party api using RestTemplate with basic configuration and required headers.
2 weeks back all calls to this external client worked fine.
I am seeing this issue only in SpringBoot java application.
Calls from postman 2 are fine and I am getting proper responses.